# How to set up my xampp so that when i type my ip to get my custom made site

Tags: url, dns

What i want to do is to set xampp so that when i give my ip to someone they can access my site. The reason for me to find something like this is cause i want to embed paypal testing to my site and it is needed to set a URL for the customers to return to my site when they complete their transactions... I run XAMPP 1.7.7 and my modem is a siemens. Also is there any free way to get a url ie blahblahblah.net or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this you will need to set up port forwarding on your router to your web server on your machine (you will have to look at your Siemens router documentation on how to do this). You will only be able to do use a custom URL if your router suports dynamic DNS, which most modern routers do. This required because probably the way you access the Internet your IP address can change each time you log in. If this is the case, you can get one free domain for this purpose at [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.org/).